# How to create Twilio conversation in a specific Chat Service?

Tags: spring, kotlin, twilio, twilio-api

I have 2 Chat Services available:

- Default Chat Service
- Flex Chat Service

Everytime I create a conversation using Conversations API, the conversation is created for the first chat service. How do I create one for specific `chatServiceId`? The code I'm using:

```
val conversation = Conversation
    .creator()
    .setDateCreated(DateTime.now())
    .create(client)
```

The client bean is created like:

```
@Bean
fun twilioClient(twilioConfiguration: TwilioConfiguration): TwilioRestClient =
    TwilioRestClient
        .Builder(twilioConfiguration.KEY, twilioConfiguration.SECRET)
        .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case is still necessary for someone.
In order to operate with a specific Conversation Service, you need to create it (via Twilio console or via REST API) and then create a conversation via this Conversation Service instance.

Use Multiservice:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/service-conversation-resource
instead of Conversation:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-resource

Answer (score -1):

Chat service are deprecated since July 2022, but if you want to add a specific one is possible to add `Chat Service SID` in your conversation object, like this:

```kotlin
val conversation = Conversation
    .creator(chatServiceSid)
    .setDateCreated(DateTime.now())
    .create(client)
```

If you don't have chatServiceSid there's two possibilities to reach this information:

1 - Recover from Twilio Console:

> - In Twilio Menu, open the chat section in left sidebar (if doesn't showing you can find in explore products) [twilio menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOFxu.png)
> - In Chat Services Overview you will see your chat services and the SID that you need to specific in code.

2 - Retrieve the Chat Service SID programmatically:

> Using Twilio API by calling the `ChatService.list()` method and
> filtering the result by name or unique identifier.

I hope that helps you. :)